# Написать программу, которая рисовала окрашенную елку в виндовс форме

Tags: c#, winforms

```
    private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
        g.Clear(Color.Blue);
        SolidBrush myCorp = new SolidBrush(Color.Green);
        SolidBrush myTrum = new SolidBrush(Color.DarkOrchid);
        SolidBrush myTrub = new SolidBrush(Color.DeepPink);
        SolidBrush mySeа = new SolidBrush(Color.Blue);
        Pen myWind = new Pen(Color.Yellow, 2);
        g.FillPolygon(myCorp, new Point[]
          {
          new Point(0,300),new Point(900,300),
          new Point(900,300),new Point(900,500),
          new Point(900,500),new Point(0,500),
          new Point(0,500),new Point(0,300),

          }
          );

    }
```

кодом нарисовал фон. дальше не могу разобраться с координатами формы. где именно рисовать елку.
помогите.

Comment: Берете бумагу в клетку, рисуете по квадратам елку, далее создаете picturebox кратного размера  рисунку на листке, пересчитываете координаты на листке в координаты в пикселях и рисуете.

Comment: Можно по клику выводить координату клика...точки запомнить и потом по ним нарисовать